# Form which generates image in real-time

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

I am looking to build a form which updates an image in real-time.

Could someone help me out and tell me the best way to go about creating a form similar to this (languages, techniques, etc): http://www.demonplates.com/platebuilder.php

Where as you enter details the image is updated accordingly. The form will send to google checkout with the data entered.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you planning to create the image from scratch, using code? Or will you be stitching one together by overlaying pre-designed letters and numbers onto an existing background?  The number plate site, might, for example, have ready-made images for each number and letter, and then superimpose them over the number plate background.  Alternatively, it may generate the text on-the-fly.  Also, how dynamic do you need it to be - should it update with every key stroke (which could generate a lot of traffic), or just once when the user submits the form?

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to use AJAX for this. Assuming the script generating the image takes a GET parameter such as: `generate_image.php?text=foo`

You can just dynamically update the `src` attribute of the image every time the contents of the input box change. Here's an example using jQuery.

```
<input type="text" id="image_text" value="your text here" />
<br />
<img src="generate_image.php?text=your+text+here" alt="generated image" id="generated_image" />
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('#image_text').change(function() {
    $('#generated_image').attr('src', $(this).val());
});
```